# Extract text using python

Tags: python-3.x, text, extract

I want to extract a specific portion from a text file.

**example** -

```
PASSED: 1  GETFILE /root/test/misc/ptolemy/erase_flash.csv  
PASSED: 4  MegaSCU -cfgclr -a0  
PASSED: 8  MegaSCU -adphwdevice -read devicetype 5 bus 1 slaveaddr 82 start 0 sz 256 -f SK83100192.vpd -a0  
PASSED: 28  VALUECHECK PACKAGE= 24.0.2-0013 in tty.log for 1 occurances!
```

From the above text I want to extract "GETFILE" , "MegaSCU", "VALUECHECK" as my output.
The file is huge and this texts are stored as column.

I am searching for any option which will help me to extract the word after "PASSED: X" in the text

Kindly help.

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Please post your code.

Comment: The raw text was first splitted on newline(\n), after which I came across the above format. Now my motive is to get the word after "PASSED: X"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with detailed issue that you encountered. General problem statement is not enough on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**
You could keep it simple and do something like the following:

```py
sample_txt = "PASSED: 1  GETFILE /root/test/misc/ptolemy/erase_flash.csv"

if sample_txt.startswith("PASSED"):
    output = " ".join(sample_txt.split(" ")[2:]).strip()
```

`output` would give the following result:

```py
>>> GETFILE /root/test/misc/ptolemy/erase_flash.csv
```

---

**Method 2**: To account for variations in whitespace you could use the `re` module

```py
import re

sample_txt = "PASSED: 28  VALUECHECK PACKAGE= 24.0.2-0013 in tty.log for 1 occurances!"

if sample_txt.startswith("PASSED"):
    output = re.split("\\s+", sample_txt)[2]
```

```
>>> VALUECHECK
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I just want "GETFILE" as my output.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another method that uses the `re` module to account for variations in whitespace. Selecting the 3rd element in the array should return the text that you want.

Comment: Much appreciated. I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume that X is always an integer.

So you can remove the start of your string "PASSED:" then read the number. Then extract until next space.

Comment: Yes, X is an integer, which is not ordered across the text file. I want to exclude the number as well, just the part after that is what needs to be extracted. Kindly help me with the logic